# css validation error moz binding?

Tags: css, validation, binding

Hi I'm a photoshop designer. I have some knowledge of css? Does anyone know what this validation error means? Am I missing something in the css?

```
    38 marquee Property -moz-binding doesn’t exist : none URI : http://etcetc.co.uk
/css/page.css 1085 input.postcode Lexical error at line 1081, column 2. Encountered: ”” (0), after : ”” } #siteMap { }
```

Thanks for your help Regards

Judi

Comment: What validation engine is that message from? `-moz-binding` is a vendor-specific property and should be left alone by validators.

Comment: Its from what my client wrote so I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-binding` is for XBL bindings. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-binding and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL